# Is it possible to rewrite floor functions applied to a fraction using only the addition, multiplication, and exponentiation operators?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let's restate this question in using mathematical notation. Let $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $f(n)=\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{k}}\right\rfloor$. Is it possible to rewrite this using the addition, multiplication, and exponentiation operators? I know it's possible for the case where $k=1$. Quite simply, note that $f(n)=\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{1}}\right\rfloor=\lfloor{n}\rfloor=n$. I know it's possible when $k=2$. Let $f(n)=\left(\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)(-1)^n$. The trick there was to start halfway between $\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{n}{2}$ and using the $(-1)^n$ term to figure out the rest.

I'm wondering if it's possible if $k=3$? I think it's possible with the use of infinite sums and trigonometric functions (though I haven't thought about that yet). However, I'd like to avoid those if necessary. I feel they may not be necessary -- though I may be wrong.

Even a slight discussion about the topic would be great.

EDIT:

So, I like the @user44197's solution. It gives rise to the solution I was looking for -- which was simpler than I thought. Let $f(n)=\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{k}}\right\rfloor$, where $n$ is a variable and $k$ is a constant (for simplicity, let $k$ be some constant in the naturals). Why not treat it like a recursion? Let $R(n) = R(n-k) + 1$. To solve this, we need to solve the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^k-1=0$. Therefore, $R_{Homogeneous}(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}n^{i}c_{i}(1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}n^{i}c_{i}$ where $c_i$ is the coefficient that will solve the recursion. Now you just need to find the non-homogeneous part, solve for the coefficients, and you're done.

Comment: Shouldn't the function be $f(n,k)$, since $f(n(,k))$ changes if $k$ changes?

Comment: $(n/2-1/4)+(1/4)(-1)^n$ uses division also (as written). Did you mean to include division as "multiplication" (in which case, are you including taking logs as "exponentiation"?) or did you mean to use $n\times(1/2)$ and treat $1/2$ as a number?

Answer (score 2):

Here is something to get started. 
Suppose you have the function
$$
f(n,k) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 & \text{if $k | n$}\\\\0 & \text{if $k \not | n$}\end{array}\right.
$$
Then you should be able to cobble together the floor function (havent't thought this through).

Let 
$$ 
\theta  = e^{i 2 \pi/k}
$$
Then 
$$
f(n,k) = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{m=0}^{k-1} \theta^ { n m}
$$
will give you such a function.

Comment: I like this solution. It gives the main idea of the solution I was looking for. If I could upvote -- I would :(

Answer (score 0):

The floor function on form of Fourrier series :

[image]